# Casting a C Struct using a Variable

Tags: c, casting

I am writing a communications protocol for a project which includes two c structs for request and response. Depending on how the device is setup, a transmission of data could be either a request (master module) or response (slave module).

The structures are very close to each other. The biggest difference is how a request is structured versus a response.

I have the variable which holds the pointer to the global variable defined as

```
unsigned int MBData;

MBData = gCommResponse;
```

When referencing the code, I would either have

```
((MBResponse*)MBData)->Address = someData;
```

or

```
((MBResponse*))MBData)->Address = someData;
```

This code is successful but would like more ambiguity for the communication functions.

What I would like to do is cast the MBData using a pointer to either the MBRequest or MBResponse.

```
unsigned int MBStruct;

MBStruct = &MBResponse;

((MBStruct*)MBData)->Address = someData; // Something like this
```

Is this possible in C programming?

Thanks.

Comment: **Do not cast an `int` to a pointer or vice versa**

Comment: @Olaf: What do you mean? I have a variable which will hold the memory location of the c struct. I assign the address of the c struct and use it as part of my casting. I am not attempting to do 'u16 *ptr = (int)12;'

Comment: `MBStruct` is an `unsigned int`, you assign a pointer to. That is plain wrong! If you do not know how to properly use pointers, please read a C book first. That is **vital** knowledge in C. Correct would be to make it a pointer to `the type of `MBResonse`. Using `void *` should be the last ressort and well justified.

Comment: @user3826668 Do not use `int` for that variable! The proper type for a pointer to an object of arbitrary type is `void*`, never `int`!

Comment: An `int` is not guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer.  If you intend to use it as such, you should define it as a `void` pointer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "This code is successful but would like more ambiguity for the communication functions." So I don't really understand what problem you are having. Anyway, to answer your question, no you can not cast a variable into a pointer to another variable. Again, I don't understand why you would want to do that.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you can create a union of two pointers (a pointer to a request and a pointer to a response), and then you can avoid casting all together. You just need to know what kind of pointer you are using.

Comment: @Stuart: The code compiled and operated successfully. I could see in memory the bytes changing when assigning values into the structure. As to why, decrease function size and clutter in the communication protocol and minimize on if statements to increase speed. From the sound of it, this is a crazy idea and should be scrapped immediately.

Comment: My problem with your question is that you say "What I would like to do is cast the MBData using a pointer to either the MBRequest or MBResponse" and then you show some code, but the code you show doesn't look smaller or less cluttered then the code you want to change. You say you want to "decrease function size and clutter in the communication protocol and minimize on if statements to increase speed" but you don't say how. What exactly do you want to do? What does casting using a pointer mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible.  When accessing a struct member, the compiler needs to know at compile time the type of the struct.

Although the two structs may have fields with common names, there's no guarantee that they are the same (or compatible) types or that they live at the same offset in their respective structs.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the two structs as a union, and by knowing if you are slave or master, access the proper fields. This assumes that a server sends a packet that is in the format the client expects, and vice versa.

To ensure the platforms of sender and receiver are of no importance, you must serialize the packets, or have some other protocol agreement by which to encode and decode packets.